# Relation between factorial and chebyshev theta function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, chebyshev-function

Let,
$$\Theta(n)=\sum_{p^{\alpha}\leq n} \ln p $$
be the second chebyshev theta function. Then is it true that,
$$\ln x!=\sum_{k\geq 1}\Theta\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$$

If yes how can I prove that?

**MY ATTEMPT:-**

$$\ln(x!)=\sum_{p\leq x}\alpha(p)\ln p$$
Where $\alpha(p)$ is the highest power of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $x!$

It's the possible expression I could think of for $ln(x!)$.
I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: What have you tried?